extending django admin by a view without a model
I have a customized admin view - my app is called virtual:
class VirtualAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    index_template = "virtual/admin_index.html"

    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        return super().index(request, extra_context)

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = path("virtual/info/", self.admin_view(self.info), name="info")
        urls.append(my_urls)
        return urls

    def info(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("hello")

and I want to be able to include the url in the newly created admin_index.html, so I did
(please ignore I used HTMX to load this bc it's shorter than AJAX in vanilla JS):
{% block content %}
    <div id="content-main">
        {% include "admin/app_list.html" with app_list=app_list show_changelinks=True %}

        Info: <h3 hx-get="{% url 'info' %}" hx-trigger="load"> loading ... </h3> 
    </div>
{% endblock %}

but I get a: Reverse for 'info' not found. 'info' is not a valid view function or pattern name error.
I already tried adding admin/ in the path, and deleting virtual but everything fails.
edit: When looping over all the urls before returning them:
<URLPattern '' [name='index']>
<URLPattern 'login/' [name='login']>
<URLPattern 'logout/' [name='logout']>
<URLPattern 'password_change/' [name='password_change']>
<URLPattern 'password_change/done/' [name='password_change_done']>
<URLPattern 'autocomplete/' [name='autocomplete']>
<URLPattern 'jsi18n/' [name='jsi18n']>
<URLPattern 'r/<int:content_type_id>/<path:object_id>/' [name='view_on_site']>
<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'virtual/product/'>
<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'virtual/store/'>
<URLPattern '^(?P<app_label>virtual)/$' [name='app_list']>
<URLPattern '(?P<url>.*)$'>
<URLPattern 'virtual/info/' [name='info']>

I see nothing too odd. Still I see a 404 in the network tab when trying to resolve: {% url 'admin:info' %}.

iirc, the namespace is admin (by the .urls property), so {% url 'admin:info' %} iirc.

If I recall correctly, the .urls of a site by default pases the url patterns as well as the app_namespace which is by default admin, and the instancce namespace, which is the name of the site you attached. Indeed, in the source code [GitHub], we see:

@property 
def urls(self):
    return self.get_urls(), "admin", self.name

You thus refer to the view with:
{% url 'admin:info' %}
Additionally, you need to provide a name for the path:
my_urls = path('virtual/info/', self.admin_view(self.info), name='info')
A final problem turned out to be that you added the path at the end of the list, and there is a "catch all" pattern before that, so you can insert it in front, or at least before the "catch all":
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    my_urls = path('virtual/info/', self.admin_view(self.info), name='info')
    urls.insert(0, my_urls)
    return urls

smart with the app_namespace ( admin) but unfortunately this is still not working :( I have the feeling the path needs adjustment? Stuck with the same error (albeit a little bit more informed now).

What if you use the name of the admin site instead of the admin:?

@xtlc: the strange thing is that I manage to get this working with the admin: part, or with the name of the site.

i do not manage to get it working, with neither of the options. Using Django 5.0.6.

when creating the view normally in the views.py and adding it to the urls.py and call it "normally" (but I used a different name to avoid interference) I managed to get it working though. I assume it is a stupid idea to call a normal view from the admin, because of some user permission checks tough? I'd love to understand how this works with an admin view.

when using admin:info: Reverse for 'info' not found. When using virtual:info: 'virtual' is not a registered namespace. When using nothing: NoReverseMatch at /admin/.

@xlc: ah, yes, but you need to give the path a proper name.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
